# How to use the spread operator to expand objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, code-cleanup

I have the following object with initial values:

```
const initialValues = {
  title: '',
  quadrants: {
    0: { name: '' },
    1: { name: '' },
    2: { name: '' },
    3: { name: '' }
  },
  rings: {
    0: { name: '' },
    1: { name: '' },
    2: { name: '' },
    3: { name: '' }
  },
};
```

I would like to extend this so that the color property is also given in the rings. I have currently solved it this way and it works. But I have the feeling that it is wrong and can be solved more cleanly:

```
  const styledConfig = {
    colors: {
      background: '#fff',
      grid: '#bbb',
      inactive: '#ddd'
    },
    rings: {
      ...config.rings,
      0: { name: config.rings[0].name, color: '#93c47d' },
      1: { name: config.rings[1].name, color: '#b7e1cd' },
      2: { name: config.rings[2].name, color: '#fce8b2' },
      3: { name: config.rings[3].name, color: '#f4c7c3' }
    }
  };
```

The result looks like this - which is right :)

```
rings: {
  0: { name: 'Ring1', color: '#93c47d' },
  1: { name: 'Ring2', color: '#b7e1cd' },
  2: { name: 'Ring3', color: '#fce8b2' },
  3: { name: 'Ring4', color: '#f4c7c3' }
},
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this cleaner?

Comment: You're not "extending" anything, you're **overwriting** the properties in `config.rings`. Any properties in the `initialValues` object will be completely overwritten by your `styledConfig` object.

Comment: Your spread syntax does nothing here since, as Aplet123 mentions, the keys 0, 1, 2, 3 are overwritten immediately. You could use a loop to set the keys more concisely though.

Comment: I noticed that. But there must be an easier way with the spread operator. It's just extending the ring object, but the keys are weird..

Comment: to avoid completely overwriting the `config.rings` properties you're adding colors to you can spread the property and just add the color property. `rings: { ...config.rings, 0: { ...config.rings[0], color: '#93c47d' },`

Comment: @pilchard But then I don't need ...config.rings, right?

Comment: You do if there are more properties that you aren't adding colors to.

Comment: I was able to simplify it like this: rings: { ...config, 0: { ...config.rings[0], color: '#93c47d' }, ...}. So I removed the name key in front and also the accessor after rings, like rings[0].rings. But is this really the cleanest way?